# I am a feeling. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> I am a feeling.
>
> I am related to money.
>
> Take last four: all people like me, lazy people more.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it

> Interest

I am a feeling.

> **Interest** is a feeling or emotion

I am related to money.

> **Interest** of the savings or loan money

Take last four: all people like me, lazy people more.

> Inte**rest**. People like to rest, especially when they are lazy.